# Using custom registration for Firebase authentication in Firebase Realtime Database (in Android)?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have implemented an Android application where the user can register to a webserver and log in with an e-mail address and a chosen password to the app. In the app, the user can use all the app features. One feature should be a chat application.

I thought about realizing the chat app with Firebase Realtime Database. To protect the access, I thought about authentification as an access rule for the database. In general, the registration would be linked to the Firebase authentication. As I have my own registration and login, I would like to ask if there is an option to use my own login data for authentification. And can it be linked to the Firebase Realtime Database?

Answer (score 0):

> As I have my own registration and login, I would like to ask if there is an option to use my own login data for authentification. And can it be linked to the Firebase Realtime Database?

You can use your own authentication, but if you want to sign in to Firebase, you need to create a [custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). Once you do that, you'll be able to write [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security).

Comment: Hey. Can I help you with other information?